# MYSQL add row and count from diffrent table

Tags: mysql, database

I have mysql database with two tables.

First (information)

```
+---------+------+----------+
| species | sex  | user     |
+---------+------+----------+
| bird    | NULL |        1 |
| bird    | f    |        1 |
| cat     | f    |        1 |
| cat     | m    |        1 |
| dog     | f    |        1 |
| dog     | m    |        2 |
| hamster | f    |        2 |
| snake   | m    |        1 |
+---------+------+----------+
```

Second (users)

```
+--------+-----+
| user   |  id |
+--------+-----+
| amy    | 1   |    
| dav    | 2   |  
| mot    | 3   |       
| mmm    | 4   | 
| aaw    | 5   | 
| dsa    | 6   |  
+--------+-----+
```

I want to count and show values from table "information" for each user row on table "users"
Like this

```
+---------+------+----------+
| user   |  id |  count     |
+---------+------+----------+
| amy    | 1    |        6  |
| dav    | 2    |        2  |
| mot    | 3    |        0  |
| mmm    | 4    |        0  |
| aaw    | 5    |        0  |
| dsa    | 6    |        0  |
+---------+------+----------+
```

How can I do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select users.user, users.id, count (species.name)
from users left join species 
on users.id = species.user
group by users.user, users.id
order by count (species.name) desc
```

Comment: The difference between my solution and that of KAJ is that I use a 'left join' whereas he uses an 'inner join'. My query will show people who have no connected pets (as per the example) whereas his will show only people who have connected pets.

Comment: Do you know how can I count only every value on row by comma?
for exmp: i have row nammed species with value "1, 2, 5, 7"
I want to count and show it as a new row with value 4

Comment: First of all, that should be a separate question. Secondly, maintaining comma delimited values is a no-no! Use a different table which assigns separate rows for each value. Try and find a book called 'SQL anti-patterns' by Bill Karwin - there is a chapter on this issue. http://www.scribd.com/doc/2670985/SQL-Antipatterns

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it something like:

```
select u.user, u.id, count(i.user)  
from user u  
  inner join information i on i.user = u.id  
group by u.user, u.id
```